# How to develop one session - multiple window applications in wicket?

Tags: wicket

How to develop an intranet application using wicket which is able to deal with multiple windows within one common seesion?

The multiple windows should work/be used independently (but sharing a common session, for example authorization data)

Comment: This should work with Wicket out of the box, as far as i know. Have you tried it and found a problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a different page map for each window/frame.

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/page-maps.html